# Calculate $\cos(\frac{2\pi}{5})$ in terms of $\sin(\frac{\pi}{5})$

Tags: trigonometry

I intend to calculate $\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{5}\right)$ via the formula 
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{5}\right)}{2}}$$
This could be expressed as:

$\sqrt{\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{8}}=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{5}\right)}{2}}$. Squaring both sides and manipulate a bit, this will give $\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{5}\right)=-\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{4}$. However, the true result is $\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4}$. What is wrong with my derivation?

Comment: What is the difference between $-\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{4}$ and $\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4}?$

Comment: @JamesWarthington Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

Note that

$$-\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{4}=(-1)\cdot\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{4}=\frac{(-1)\cdot1-(-1)\cdot(\sqrt{5})}{4}=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4}$$

Comment: You are right, I am doing too many excercises today, my head is weird now. Thanks!

Comment: @JamesWarthington LOL, never mind! Take a rest! You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 1):

Relax, your answer is correct.

Just multiply the top by $-1$ and you will get   $$\cos(\frac{2\pi}{5})=-\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{4}= \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to square or manipulate whatever, if you used the relevant one of the *duplication formulæ*:

$$\cos 2\theta=\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1=1-2\sin^2\theta.$$